# What uml diagrams can be used for a data science project

Tags: uml, data-science

I am working on a data science project for my 3-2 mini project. My project analyzes the performance of a country in the Olympics based on some attributes. But I am confused about the UML diagrams I should be using in my project.

Comment: Whatever you need. You did not tell us your needs. So we can't answer that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some 15 UML diagram types out there. A sensible sequence of diagrams to be created depends on your approach. 
If you'd like to create an analysis model that is a conceptual model of your problem domain then a sensible sequence of diagrams might be:

1. Usecase diagrams
2. Activity diagrams
3. Class diagrams

and if your project gets bigger you might need package diagrams.

If you'd like to create a design model that is a conceptual model of your solution domain then a sensible sequence of diagrams might be:
 1. Component diagrams
 2. Class diagrams
 3. Sequence diagrams
 4. Statecharts

In both cases a starting point is having a diagram for your system context. Some people like to mix component and usecase diagram features to denote a system context.

The aspects you might want to take into concideration of your diagram choices are:

- syntax - how strictly would you like to follow the UML standard and what use does adhering to the standard have for you
- semantics - what is your need - what do you want to document - and who needs to understand it
- pragmatics - what is the best way to achieve your projects goal e.g. being efficient and effective
- tool - what tools do you have at hand and are used and known to your peers - what can you afford to invest in keeping the tool infrastructure up

Comment: @Lohitaa at stackoverflow you can expect answers for general questions that might also be interesting to others. Your request is for an individual consultancy which i do offer but not on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

While your question is very broad, I could imagine that in view of:

> My project analyzes the ***performance*** of a ***country*** in the Olympics based on some ***attributes***.

you'll certainly need a [class-diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html).  Because the class diagram will clarify what kind of objects your software will manipulate (e.g. Olympic game, Participating countries, Teams, Athletes, Discipline, Competition), how they are related, and what attributes are associated with which each.

This will enable you to determine for the different analysis you want the access path to the relevant attributes.  It will also allow you to find missing attributes, and to desing a convenient interface for the different classes.

You may also use other diagrams.  But with the few requirements you've shared, it's difficult to guess which one and I do not want to do a lot of guesses.  I could nevertheless imagine that a use-case diagram could help to give the big picture of who is going to do what with your software.

Comment: I have followed your instructions and it helped me. Thank you.